# ProperCase in SSIS where name has hyphen

Tags: ssis

I am trying to transform the 'firstname' column from its initial state: all upper case (e.g. FLORIN, FLORIN-MIHAI) to proper case (e.g. Florin, Florin-Mihai).
I`ve used the expression below

```
REPLACE(LEFT(FIRSTNAME,1) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(FIRSTNAME,2,100))," ","")
```

and it works for names without hyphen (e.g. FLORIN = Florin), but where my names have hyphen it doesn't  (FLORIN-MIHAI = Florin-Mihai and I am looking for Florin-Mihai).
Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: Please accept your answer, so others only come here for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Original Poster answered his own question with the following script component (transformation):

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer) 
Row.FIRSTNAME = StrConv(Row.FIRSTNAME, VbStrConv.ProposerCase) 
End Sub
```